# Using a JSON-API server library in a Ktor application

Tags: kotlin, json-api, ktor

I have a Ktor application (in Kotlin) and would like the endpoints to be exposed according to the JSON:API specification. I understand my library options are between the Java server libraries for JSON:API, i.e. [Katharsis](https://katharsis-jsonapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (which gives code examples for Dropwizard, Spring Boot etc.) and [Crnk](http://www.crnk.io/) (which gives example for Spring Boot). I have tried a bit with Katharsis but it's not clear to me how the ResourceRepositoryV2 class should be registered/exposed by the Ktor application.

Any examples or pointers?